# Share Relay nodeInterface

Tags: relayjs, graphql, graphql-js

I want to share a single nodeInterface with multiple GraphQL types.   Currently getting this error:

```
Error: User may only implement Interface types, it cannot implement: undefined.
```

I have declared the interface like this:

```
// file: node-interface.js
let {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    let {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
    if (type === 'UserModel') {;
      return UserModel.findOne(id).exec();
    }
    return null;
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof UserModel) {
      return UserType;
    }
    return null;
  }
);

export { nodeInterface };
export { nodeField };

and attempting to use it in my UserType like this 

// file: user.js
import {
  nodeInterface
} from ‘./node-interface';

let UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A user',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    username: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

What am I missing? I need to be able to break up the declaration of multiple GraphQL types into corresponding files and implement the nodeInterface...

Comment: Not sure but you might need to put the types into a registry module to break the nodeinterface<->user circular dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is necessary to create a type registry for a schema of any substance. See example here:

[Type Registry](https://gist.github.com/taion/d161a58b9f7381d8fa9c)

and then create the nodeInterface and nodeField like this:

```
// ./src/schema/node.js
import { nodeDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';

import { idFetcher, typeResolver } from './registry';

export const { nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(
  idFetcher, typeResolver
);
```

checkout this issue for more info: [Abstract type resolution](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/issues/25)

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate on this a little bit more for beginners? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thunk:

```
// interfaces: [nodeInterface]
interfaces: () => [nodeInterface]
```

---

[details](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype):

```
type GraphQLObjectTypeConfig = {
    name: string;
    interfaces?: GraphQLInterfacesThunk | Array<GraphQLInterfaceType>;
    fields: GraphQLFieldConfigMapThunk | GraphQLFieldConfigMap;
    isTypeOf?: (value: any, info?: GraphQLResolveInfo) => boolean;
    description?: ?string
}

type GraphQLInterfacesThunk = () => Array<GraphQLInterfaceType>;
```

Comment: You can and should elaborate on your answer, explain what it does, why it works, things like this.